# Retrieving Bitlocker Recovery Keys from AD

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

Fairly new to Powershell, I managed to get the following code to retrieve the Bitlocker key for computers in the domain, however, I have an issue with it:

```
Clear-Host
$TestOU = "OU=ABC,DC=XYZ,DC=com"
$PCs = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $TestOU
$Results = ForEach ($Computer in $PCs)
{
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
ComputerName = $Computer.Name
RecoveryPassword = Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectclass -eq "msFVE- 
RecoveryInformation"' -SearchBase $computer.DistinguishedName -Properties 
msFVE-RecoveryPassword,whencreated | sort whencreated -Descending | select 
msfve-recoverypassword
}
}
$Results
```

My output for each password begins with {a{msfve-recoverypassword= and I'm not sure how to remove this.

Comment: I think that you can use the split method...

Comment: Try changing `select 
msfve-recoverypassword` to `select -ExpandProperty
msfve-recoverypassword`

Comment: Thanks, -ExpandProperty worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives useful output for human consumption in the shell, but may also be used in a script:

```bsh
$computer = Get-ADComputer $computerName
Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "msFVE-RecoveryInformation"' -SearchBase $computer.DistinguishedName -Properties whenCreated, msFVE-RecoveryPassword | `
  Sort whenCreated -Descending | Select whenCreated, msFVE-RecoveryPassword
```